# Best way to handle model data over multiple views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I know this has been asked in several different ways, but I am not sure my specific problem has been asked.  Due to Business rules, I can not use a db for temp storage of data between views.  Static Variables are out (multi-user). I'm trying to avoid session and tempdata.  I'll be storing about 9-12 models worth of data that will slow page load if I use Viewstate.  I have multi-paged forms that will need to be refilled if the user returns to a form.  I know this isn't the ideal way, but can anyone suggest a way to persist this data for multiple models other than session variables?  Tempdata would need to be re-written per view I assume.  I can't supply code and I know this is not a favorable design, but the rules are constricting.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you avoiding Session data?  That is exactly what they are used for...

Comment: Could your view model be a composition of pages and thus each page would be filled as the user moved from page to page and since you'd be passing the whole model to these pages if the user went back a page you would populate it from you model.

Comment: I with @kadumel on this. I tend to use the Singleton pattern, using statics over session storage to compile say... steps of a wizard before final submission to the database. This is what session storage was made for. If you absolutely *cannot* use session for reasons unknown to us, you could consider using HTML5 storage w/JSON, but I wouldn't recommend it due to browser limitations and a varying standard of implementation therein thus far. http://caniuse.com/#search=storage

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with using Session, even for MVC.  It's a tool, use it when you need it.  I find that most people tend to avoid Session because the code is usually pretty ugly.  I like to use a Generic Wrapper around objects I need to store in session which provide a Strongly-Typed and Re-usable Class (example):

```
public abstract class SessionBase<T> where T : new()
{
    private static string Key
    {
        get { return typeof(SessionBase<T>).FullName; }
    }

    public static T Current
    {
        get
        {
            var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] as T;

            // if you never want to return a null value
            if (instance == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] = instance = new T();
            }

            return instance;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] = value;
        }
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] as T;
        if (instance != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Create your class that needs to be stored:

```
[Serializable]  // The only requirement
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Create your Concrete type:  (Really really easy?)

```
public class PersonSession : SessionBase<Person> { }
```

Use it whenever you want, with whatever you want (as long as it's serializable)

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
  var Person = db.GetPerson();

  PersonSession.Current = Person;

  this.View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(Person)
{
  if (Person.FirstName != PersonSession.Current.FirstName)
  {
    // etc, etc 

    PersonSession.Clear();
  }
}
```